# About the timing of calling the Start Commit Hook

Tags: git, hook, tortoisegit

I created a form program using PyQt and bound it with a Start Commit Hook. When I click the submit button, the form program will first pop up (the form program provides some fixed input boxes for standardizing log information). Additionally, I configured the `[commit] template=/Users/xxx/commitlog.txt` in .git/config, and the form program will concatenate the user filled content and write it into the path file of the template configuration. However, the log information in the submission window displays the content written last time. How can I display the newly written content in the submission log input box after calling the Start Commit Hook?

I look forward to entering my log information when clicking on submit and displaying it in the input box of the submit window instead of displaying the information from the last submission.

Comment: Does https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-hooks help you?